# Rearranging of terms of a series

Tags: real-analysis

If a series is conditionally convergent then we know by Riemann theorem that different arrangements of terms may lead to different sums but if series is absolutely convergent will it always give same sum for every rearrangement ?

Comment: Yes it will. Absolutely convergent is equivalent to commutatively convergent (also for series with complex terms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. For details, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Rearrangements_and_unconditional_convergence) link with a rather nice proof (note that the proof only requires completeness of the group in which the sum is calculated, and $\mathbb R$, of course, is complete).